# Fill an polygon with dynamic text and dynamic size

Tags: javascript, php, css, image-processing

I have no clue, whether there is almost an solution for my problem nor if it is at all possible to do solve this.

What I want to do:
I have a picture of polygones. It's a abstract drawing of a persons. Something like [this](http://image.pixelio.de/000/362/837//player/1--362837-Familie-pixelio.jpg)

Now I want to fill each polygon (dynamically) with text strings (containing names). The result should be the drawing with the various text snippets inside the polygones.

The text snippets will come from a database. The picture should generate dynamically and will be displayed on a website.

I have no clue if this is possible, which technology or library to use.

Would be very kind, if someone has an hint where to start the search or which keywords to use for searching. Perhaps there is already a library in php, javascript or else which does such things.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`GD Library in PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to do this.

[**Here**](http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-gd-library-adding-text-writing.php) is a simple example how you can write text on the image. *[Yeah .. Dynamically]*

Comment: Thanks for that. But I already know that. I am very familiar with php,mysql,css and js. It's a kind of daily business for me. So the question is probably a bit missunderstood. I am searching for a class or a library which draws various text into a polygon and takes care of the polygone borders and places the text so that everything fits together. Combining my link from the question with this link may help understanding my problem. http://downloads2.esri.com/MappingCenter2007/ask/test1.png